Find expected value of the time between a markov chain leaving x and coming back to it
Hey I'm having trouble in the subject of Markov chains and expected values, would've liked some clarification.
Assuming we have a hyperconnected Markov chain with a transformation matrix P and a stationary distribution π, with X0=x (the initial state). And T is the time between the chain leaving the value x and coming back to it.
I need to A: calculate the expected value E(T) using π(x) and Pxx.
B: infer that π(x) <= 1/(2-Pxx).
I have a hard time connecting between distributions and expected values so I'd love your help.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@JoséCarlosSantos Hi Jose, not sure how to rephrase this question. This is all the information I'm supposed to be solving it by, and I'm stuck on how to even start.

This problem is unclear. I'm going to answer what I think you are asking. (I would comment first to get some more information but don't have enough reputation to leave comments.)  I have never seen use of the term "hyperconnected" for a Markov chain but I'm guessing it has to do with communication between all states and hopefully results in the chain being positive recurrent. (You might have a problem here if you have an infinite state space and only null recurrence.) In the positive recurrent case, you would have that the long-run probability of the chain being in state $x$ is one over the mean return time to $x$:
$$
\tag{1}
\pi(x) = \frac{1}{E[T]}.
$$
I'm also guessing that $P_{xx}$ is the probability of the chain going from state $x$ to $x$ in one step. (If so, I think that $p_{xx}$ would be better notation.)
With this, you could use a first-step analysis to say that the chain

has to take $1$ step, after which
it goes right back to $x$ in $1$ step with probability $p_{xx}$ and it has to take $0$ more steps, or
it goes from $x$ to a different state $y$, after which you have to start counting the number of time steps to go from state $y$ to state $x$.

If we define this number of steps as
$$
u_{y} = E[T|X_{0}=y]
$$
where $T = \min \{n \geq 1: X_{0} =x\}$,
we have
$$
E[T] = 1 + p_{xx} \cdot 0 + \sum_{y \ne x} p_{xy} \, u_{y}. 
$$
Since, for $y \ne x$, we must have $u_{y} \geq 1$, we can say that
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
E[T] &\geq& 1 + p_{xx} \cdot 0 + \displaystyle\sum_{y \ne x} p_{xy} \cdot 1\\[1em]
&=& 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{y \ne x} p_{xy}\\[1em]
&=& 1 + (1-p_{xx})\\[1em]
&=& 2-p_{xx}.
\end{array}
$$
This, combined with (1) gives the desired result.
